# Foot slipped off clutch while downshifting. Damage?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, damage

I have an '08 Honda Fit with a 5-speed manual transmission.  I hit a steep hill earlier today and decided to downshift from 3rd to 2nd, so I didn't ride the brake for several miles.  Before my RPMs had come up and while the clutch was still slipping, my foot slipped from the clutch pedal, causing the car to lurch back pretty hard and causing a click sound to come from under the car (forward, probably from the transmission).

After driving stick for years, this is the first time such a thing happens (I was wearing a new pair of shoes).  I wonder what sort of damage can occur as a result of this sort of situation.  I drove the remaining several miles home and the car seemed to be in perfect working order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's not good for the engine, transmission, clutch, or other drive train parts, I doubt you've done any damage to the vehicle. Do realize that actions like this will cause damage over time. This is called stress damage as parts were only made to sustain so much stress before they fail. If this is the first time, there shouldn't be anything to worry about.